# Find all input elements in visible area of scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a scrollable div of fixed size in which there are 500 rows. Each rows has 6 columns of input, textarea, select elements.

Instead of selecting all the input elements, I want to find all the input elements that are currently visible on the screen (i.e Input elements in viewport of the div).

For eg. If I am on item 320 and I can see elements upto 350, I only need to select input elements in that range

Here is trimmed version of 1 row in the scrollable box:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="prm_1_1_1_100" type="checkbox" value="" name="checkbox" style="display: none;">
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="dsp_1_1_2_2"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="dsp_1_1_1_5" type="text" value="" maxlength="16" minlength="16" required="true" data-allow="alphanumeric">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="dsp_1_1_1_6" type="text" value="" maxlength="500" required="true">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="dsp_1_1_1_7" type="text" value="" required="true" data-max-date="today" data-toggle="datepicker" class="hasDatepicker">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="dsp_1_1_1_8" type="text" value="" maxlength="20" data-allow="toFixedDecimal">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="dsp_1_1_1_9" type="text" value="" data-allow="toFixedDecimal">
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea id="dsp_1_1_1_22" rows="1" cols="20" required="true" onkeyup="javascript: getVals(this, 'textarea');"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="dsp_1_1_1_23">
                <option value="RLB" selected="selected">RLB</option>
                <option value="CLB">CLB</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="dsp_1_1_1_14" disabled="disabled">
                <option value="Open" selected="selected">Open</option>
                <option value="Drop">Drop</option>
                <option value="MAP">MAP</option>
                <option value="Carry Over"> Carry Over</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="dsp_1_1_1_15" type="text" value="" disabled="disabled" class="width-80">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="dsp_1_1_1_16" type="text" value="" disabled="disabled" class="width-80">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Please display your HTML!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter by the `scrollTop` position relative to each row top position:

```
function getElements ($scroll) {
    var viewportStart = $scroll.scrollTop();
    var viewportEnd = viewportStart + $scroll.height();

    return $scroll.find('tr, .row').filter(function() {
        var $row = $(this);
        var rowTop = $row.position().top;
        return rowTop >= viewportStart && rowTop <= viewportEnd;
    });
};

var $container = $('div.scroll');    // $('table')

getElements($container).css('backgroundColor', '#00f');
```

Comment: @AjayKumar. I'm glad to hear this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a jQuery plugin to do just this!

The range start needs to be the offset, not the top position.

***Note:*** *Make sure to hit the* <kbd>[image] Full page</kbd> *button in the code snippet below to see more rows.*

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.findVisibleScroll = function(config) {
    var defaults = { selector : '' };
    if (!$.isPlainObject(config)) config = { selector : config };
    config = $.extend(true, defaults, config || {});
    var viewRangeStart = $(this).offset().top;
    var viewRangeEnd = viewRangeStart + this.height();
    return this.find(config.selector).filter(function() {
      var eleTop = $(this).offset().top;
      var eleBottom = eleTop + $(this).height();
      return (eleBottom <= viewRangeEnd) && (eleTop >= viewRangeStart);
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
  for (var row = 0; row < 500; row++) {
    var $row = $('<tr>').appendTo($('table').first().append($('<tbody>')));
    for (var col = 0; col < 6; col++) {
      $('<td>').append($('<input>', { placeholder : row + ' x ' + col })).appendTo($row);
    }
  }
});

$('.select-btn').on('click', function() {
  $('.viewport-half-vertical').find('tr').removeClass('selected');
  $('.viewport-half-vertical').findVisibleScroll('tr').addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.scrollable {
  overflow: scroll;
}
.viewport-half-vertical {
  max-height: 50vh;
  width: 100%'
}
.viewport-half-vertical table {
    border-spacing: 0.125em;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
.viewport-half-vertical table td {
  padding: 0.0625em;
  text-align: center;
}
.viewport-half-vertical table input {
  width: 99%;
  text-align: center;
}
.selected {
  background: #AAF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Select Elements in Viewport</h1>
<div class="viewport-half-vertical scrollable">
  <table></table>
</div>
<button class="select-btn">Select Visible</button>
```